# Whats the best way to make comunicate the dart code with the java code in flutter?

Tags: java, flutter, dart

im working on a simple app in flutter and i think im overthinking. What is the best and most efficient way to make dart communicate with java?
I've seen people using http requests but I don't have a server that can respond to http requests.

So I'm trying to use the system with the MethodChannel but I can't get the code to work as intended.
Are there better systems besides this one? Are there any guides or example app you can recommend for using these systems?

Comment: What is your end goal? simple apps don't need to communicate with the native side, and I see you mentioning http requests which can  be done using libraries such as Dio, so please clarify what is your goal behind talking to the native side?

Comment: My goal is send to the dart code the information to parse so he the view will show the correct data on screen.

Comment: check this article it will help you understand how Dart/Flutter communicate with the runtime environment https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels